# English auto-generated subtitles, youtube-dl

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, youtube-dl, video-subtitles

I'm using youtube-dl version 2021.12.17.
I'm trying to download from youtube some English subtitles with
valid time specifiers.
When the youtube video has an English transcript and only autogenerated subtitles,
I will use a  command such as:

```
youtube-dl --skip-download --write-auto-sub --sub-lang de,en,it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnz0zKpxryY -o qnz
```

Result:
the subtitle files for German (qnz.de.vtt) and Italian (qnz.it.vtt) are good, but the subtitle file for English (qnz.en.vtt) has three parts:
part_1: a very simple header
part_2: the complete text in one line
part_3: timing information, with no text associated
something like:
00:00:26.310 --> 00:00:29.189 align:start position:0%

Instead of what I get from qnz.de.vtt which is much richer as in:
00:00:26.320 --> 00:00:29.189 align:start position:0%
henry und eliza ein roman, der
demütig <00:00:26.999>miss <00:00:27.678>cooper <00:00:28.357>
gewidmet <00:00:29.036>ist

In this format, I can't figure out which text should appear at what time.
Thanks to anybody willing to help me in this matter.
Eventually, is there another cli command (for Linux) that could solve the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Duplicated with [this answered Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74921870).